# How to check how many times a word appears in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, count, text-files

I've seen a few people ask how this would be done, but their questions were 'too broad' so I decided to find out how to do it. I've posted below how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to do this, first you must open the file (Assuming you have a file of text called 'text.txt') We do this by calling the open function.

```
file = open('text.txt', 'r')
```

The open function uses the syntax: open(file, mode)

The file being the text document, and the mode being how it's opened. ('r' means read only) The read function just reads the file, then split separates each of the words into a list object. Lastly, we use the count function to find how many times the word appears.

```
word = input('word: ')
print(file.read().split().count(word))
```

And there you have it, counting words in a text file!

Comment: I don't like that you use `file` as a name for the variable, because it overwrites the [built-in function `file`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file). Then you change the meaning of `file` in your code (first it's a file descriptor, then it's a list of words) and you don't close the file. Working code, but bad style.

Comment: @Matthias there is no built in function called file.

Comment: "Except. Except Ben will be disappointed when Ben's count of 'ben' or 'Except' will except words that have differing capital letters, apostrophes or punctuation"

Answer (score 1):

Word counts can be tricky. At a minimum, one would like to avoid differences in capitalization and punctuation. A simple way to take the next step in word counts is to use regular expressions and to convert its resulting words to lower case before we do the count. We could even use `collections.Counter` and count all of the words.

```
import re

# `word_finder(somestring)` emits all words in string as list
word_finder = re.compile(r'\w+').findall

filename = input('filename: ')
word = input('word: ')

# remove case for compare
lword = word.lower()

# `word_finder` emits all of the words excluding punctuation
# `filter` removes the lower cased words we don't want
# `len` counts the result
count = len(list(filter(lambda w: w.lower() == lword,
    word_finder(open(filename).read()))))
print(count)

# we could go crazy and count all of the words in the file
# and do it line by line to reduce memory footprint.
import collections
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

word_counts = collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    word_finder(line.lower()) for line in open(filename)))
print(pprint(word_counts))
```

Answer (score 1):

Splitting on whitespace isn't sufficient -- split on everything you're not counting and get your case under control:

```
import re
import sys

file = open(sys.argv[1])

word = sys.argv[2]

print(re.split(r"[^a-z]+", file.read().casefold()).count(word.casefold()))
```

You can add apostrophes to the inverted pattern `[^a-z']` or whatever else you want to include in your count.

**Hogan**: Colonel, you're asking and answering your own questions. That's tops in German efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

```
def words_frequency_counter(filename):
    """Print how many times the word appears in the text."""
    try:
        with open(filename) as file_object:
            contents = file_object.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    else:
        word = input("Give me a word: ") 
        print("'" + word + "'" + ' appears ' + 
            str(contents.lower().count(word.lower())) + ' times.\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to open the file. Do this with:

```
your_file = open('file.txt', 'r')
```

Next, you want to count the word. Let's set your word as `brian` under the variable `life`. No reason.

```
your_file.read().split().count(life)
```

What that does is reads the file, splits it into individual words, and counts the instances of the word 'brian'. Hope this helps!

Comment: I posted this to answer my own question; I know how to do it, I wanted to share that with everyone else. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox *facepalm :)